# Can't disable gcc warning - make pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: linux, gcc, gcc-warning

tried many methods, ex:

```
-fsyntax-only
-Wno-format
```

still got this warning:

```
xxxxx passing argument x of xxxx make pointer from integer without a cast
```

I want to disable this warning in any way.

//////////////////////

update:

in order to follow the rule here, I provide the specific code:

here is the source code I was testing:

https://github.com/vladermolaev/jam2ftdi

It can build successfully by Visual Studio.

However, I want to test it in Linux, I built it in Linux.

I saw the error log as I described in this issue.

Here is the problem code, the problem is the third input parameter, unsinged char *tdo.

because when calling this function in this project, it takes int as input parameter, not unsinged char*

https://github.com/vladermolaev/jam2ftdi/blob/master/FTDI_API.h#L5

```
int FTDI_WriteTMSandTDIandReadTDO(const unsigned char tms, const unsigned char tdi, unsigned char *tdo);
```

therefore, I already know it works since I built in Windows OS, I don't want to change code everywhere in linux platform.

Hope this is clear, and please unlock this issue.

Thanks.

///////////////////////

update:

for which line caused this error:

https://github.com/vladermolaev/jam2ftdi/blob/9af9c7a055707b178e5aa91ae4447686256a4790/JAMSTUB.C#L328

```
tdo = FTDI_WriteTMSandTDIandReadTDO(tms, tdi, read_tdo);
```

the usage in this project, read_tdo is int which generated this compiling warning.

Comment: Just fix it.  Show us the code and we'll help.  The warnings exist for good reason; disabling them is rarely a good idea

Comment: Disabling the warning is a bad idea. Just fix the code. (Adding a cast is the simplest fix, but probably not the best one.)

Comment: And... if you are having to add a cast to get around a warning (other than `void*` when printing pointers), you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I fixed by patch the code, since I know the code is working correctly, I am porting it, I don't want to patch everywhere again, and I just want to know how to suppress it

Comment: *"I fixed by patch the code ..."* - If you don't know how to cast to convert datatypes and correct widths, then how can you be certain the code is correct? You really need to show your code.

Comment: As far as I understand, the asker reuses the code **written** (and supported!) by **someone else**. In that case, it is very good intention to not modify the other's code, and, from the other side, tending to remove warnings caused by that code. Not sure why that close votes and requests for show that code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: OP is cutting up the error messages and leaving out important pieces.  Without being told what line of code is causing the warning, it's nearly impossible to help.

Comment: that line should be `FTDI_WriteTMSandTDIandReadTDO(tms, tdi, &tdo)`, and the declaration of `tdo` needs to change to the correct type.

Comment: yup, I know how to fix it. I want to know how to suppress this message in gcc(linux),  since the same code I can build pass in visual studio.

Comment: According to [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), this option should help: `-Wno-int-to-pointer-cast`.

Comment: I tested your answer '-Wno-int-to-pointer-cast', it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this parameter for gcc as following:

-Wno-int-to-pointer-cast

it solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this option: `-Wnoint-conversion`. It will suppress warnings about incompatible integer to pointer and pointer to integer conversions.
***Note***: `-Wno-int-to-pointer-cast` doesn't work in this case. This warning is given when there is an ***explicit*** cast to a pointer from an integer ***of a different size***.